# How to create a regular expression to partition a string that terminates in either ": 45" or ",", without the ": "

Tags: python, search, python-re, group

The strings are of the form:

```
Item 5. Some text: 48
Item 5E. Some text,
```

The result of the search should produce
4 groups as follows.

```
Group(1) = "#"
Group(2) = "5" or "5E"
Group(3) = "Some text"
Group(4) = "48" or ","
```

I have tried:

```
r"(.*)Group (.*)\.(.+)(?::(.+))|(,)"
r"(.*)Group (.*)\.(.+)(?:(?::(.+))|(,))"
r"(.*)Group (.*)\.(.+)(:(.+))|(,)"
```

It have tried a variety of ways to solve this, but none work as required.
What should the regular expression be?

Comment: All of your expressions include the word "Group", but your strings don't.  Also why would Group(1) produce "#".  This makes no sense.

Comment: FWIW, the first and last regexes are definitely wrong due to `|(,)`. That's an alternate for the *entire expression*, not just the end.